# Detect click on checkbox in custom ListView layout?

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox, onitemclicklistener

I know there's tons of other threads around about this same topic, but none of them seem to work with my scenario and I couldn't get my listview to work with their code. Basically, I'm using a SimpleCursorAdapter to populate a listview with items from the database. Each listview row uses a custom layout which consists of a checkbox and a line of simple text. How do I detect a click on the checkbox? I know I need to use OnItemClickListener, but I don't know how to incorporate that into my code. Here's my code:

```
remindersCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                         R.xml.view_reminders_item_layout,
                         remindersCursor, new String [] { RemindersDAO.NAME },
                         new int[] { R.id.view_reminders_item_text } );

viewRemindersListView.setAdapter(remindersCursorAdapter);
```

R.xml.view_reminders_item_layout is the custom listview layout file. How do I capture the checkbox from this file and set a click listener to it? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Your layout ought to be in a `/res/layout` folder, not the `/res/xml` folder. However to properly use a CheckBox only OnClickListener in an adapter you must write a custom adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check the checkbox when a item is clicked, you can do it by setting checked status of Checkbox in onItemClick method.

```
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

       // now get the checkbox view. Then set the checked status.
        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check_box);
        checkBox.setChecked(!checkbox.isChecked());
  }
```

If you want to detect the click on only checkbox then set the focusable true in xml.
     // in your custom list view item. It takes the current view focus.

```
      <Checkbox>
          android:focusable="true"
      </Checkbox>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply! I actually want to detect a click on the checkbox ONLY, not the entire listview row. How do I do that?

Comment: Could you explain with code? I'm new to Android development and don't know how to carry out your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Do I place the method above, outside the onCreate() method?

Comment: No. Go to your custom row xml ( view_reminders_item_layout.xml ) file which will show a TextView and a Checkbox. Add this line under CheckBox tag.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17339/discussion-between-knvarma-and-user1666541)